# Prove that $I\oplus J $ and $(I \cap J)\oplus R$ are isomorphic as $R$-modules.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, ideals

Let $R$ be a ring with 1, let $I,J$ left ideals such that $I+J=R$. I'm trying to prove that $I\oplus J  $ and $(I \cap J)\oplus R$ are isomorphic as $R$-modules.

Help?

Comment: What's the difference **for you** between *your* $\;I+J\;$ and *your* $\;I\oplus J\;$ ? Or is it given that ideal sum is a direct one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the exact sequence
$$0\longrightarrow I\cap J\longrightarrow I\oplus J\longrightarrow R\longrightarrow 0$$
with morphisms given by $x\in I\cap J\mapsto (x,-x)$ and $(x,y)\in I\oplus J\mapsto x+y$.
Since $R$ is a free (hence projective) $R$-module, the sequence splits giving rise to the direct sum decomposition $I\oplus J\cong (I\cap J)\oplus R$.

For example, if $1=a+b$ with $a\in I$ and $b\in J$ then the morphism $x\in R\mapsto x(a,b)$ splits the sequence.

Comment: *If $1=a+b$ with $a\in I$ and $b\in J$ then the morphism [...] split the sequence* Er, well the sequence doesn't split as a result of $I+J=R$ *per se*. The sequence, as written, isn't exact without that. The more pertinent reason it splits is that $R$ is a projective module. Because, for example, one could imagine writing the sequence where $I,J$ are submodules of some other module $M$ instead of $R$, where $I+J=M$, and then one needs to know something about $M$ (like if it is projective.)

Comment: The exactness at $R$ follows from $I+J=R$.

Comment: Yes I agree it *does* but I just kind of feel like the real reason why is concealed in a sort of one-off explanation. I suppose it suffices just fine to find this splitting map but...